# Understanding a 'density' function in Probability with Martingales

Tags: probability-theory

I'm reading David Williams' "Probability with Martingales" and I'm a bit confused about one of his examples. He says:

*Consider for a moment what is in some ways a bad attempt to construct a 'probability theory'. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the class of subsets $C$ of $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,...\}$ for which the 'density'
$$\rho(C):=\lim_{n \uparrow \infty}n^{-1}\#\{k:1 \leq k \leq n; k \in C\}$$
exists.*

And I can't see how this wouldn't exist? Often it equals zero, sure, but when does it not exist? I think, perhaps, I've not got a real understanding of what this density actually is. He says later that

*We might like to think of this density (if it exists) as 'the probability that a number chosen at randoms belongs to $C$'.*

But that doesn't seem to help my problem of understanding when it does **not** exist.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the ratio inside your limit, call it $\rho_n$. Take $a_k$ as the number of elements of $C$ between $2^{k-1}$ and $2^k$. Then
$$ \rho_{2^{2n}} = \frac{1}{2^{2n}} \sum_{k=1}^{2n} a_k = \frac{1}{2^{2n}} \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{2k}+ \frac{1}{2^{2n}} \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{2k-1} $$
$$ \rho_{2^{2n+1}} = \frac{1}{2}\rho_{2n} + \frac{1}{2^{2n+1}} a_{2n+1} $$
Now set $a_{2k-1}=0$, $a_{2k}=2^{2k-1}$ (so $C$ contains the integers larger than an odd but smaller than the next even power of $2$). We find
$$ \rho_{2^{2n}} = \frac{1}{2^{2n}} \sum_{k=1}^{2n} a_k = \frac{1}{4^{n}} \sum_{k=1}^{n} 2^{2k-1} = \frac{2}{3}\frac{4^{n}-1}{4^n} \to \frac{2}{3} $$
as $n \to \infty$, whereas
$$ \rho_{2^{2n+1}} = \frac{1}{3}(1-4^{-n}) + 0 \to \frac{1}{3}, $$
so we have two subsequences of $\rho_m$ with different limits, so $ \lim_{m\to\infty}{\rho_m} $ cannot exist, and the density of this set is not defined.

This is one example, but you can obviously make others by fiddling with the definitions of $a_k$.